# How to derive the variance premium formula

Tags: calculus, probability, actuarial-science

How to derive formula (5.5) with Taylor's expansion in the following link?

The difficult part of my question is that i had never seen Var(S) appear in Taylor's expansion

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0dyh.png

EDIT: Let $\kappa_S(R)=\log(\mathrm{E}[e^{RS}])$, where $S$ is an aggregate loss random variable, and $R$ is a risk parameter (constant).

(5.5) $\pi(S)=\frac{1}{R}\kappa_S(R)=\frac{1}{R}[\mathrm{E}(S)R+\mathrm{Var}(S)\frac{R^2}{2}+...]\approx\mathrm{E}(S)+\mathrm{Var}(S)\frac{R}{2}$

So the OP's question is why $\mathrm{Var}(S)$ shows up in the Taylor series of $\kappa_S(R)=\log(\mathrm{E}[e^{RS}])$.

Comment: I cannot even read that. Is it possible to type out your question? Regards

Comment: @Amzoti - You could use zoom on the Internet explorer

Comment: Dear @Victor : Trying to force readers to accommodate you might reduce the number of responses. You're more likely to get good responses if you try to type it out (people will help you get the rendering right).

Comment: Roughly speaking (and why this is not an answer), apply taylor's theorem to $e^{RS}$, and then take the expectation.  Taking the expectation of a squared variable involves the variance.

Comment: Following on from Trutl's comment, the formula (5.5) is the _cumulant generating function_, and the second cumulant is the variance.  See this Wolfram article: [cumulant generating function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cumulant-GeneratingFunction.html)